# How to use radio buttons whose options are other html elements

Tags: php, javascript, html, radio-button

How would you create radio buttons whose options are other html elements?
For instance, I need two radio buttons - the first will show a dropdown menu and the other - a simple text field.
The dropdown menu will get its options from the DB and the user will be able to choose one of these options and hit "submit".
But he could also choose to fill the text field and hit "submit" instead.

Comment: Please provide some code as to where you have gotten so far and we can assist you further.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you want a bit more clearly. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I don't have code to provide yet. I'm just trying this for the first time. The idea is that a user will have to submit an address. So, he will be able to choose one of several existing addresses (the dropdown menu) or if non of them suits him, he will be able to enter the address by himself (the text field option).

Answer (score 1):

Create a div container that will hold your text field/drop down. Add an onChange trigger to the radio that gets its value and if its value is lets say 'textbox', use appendChild to add a textbox to the container. Same for the drop down.

Comment: Thanks Jonah. Can you please show what you mean with a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You should put an "onchange" event trigger on the radio tags.  The javascript can be whatever you want; I would think that you would give a unique ID to the dropdown menu and text field, and toggle the CSS display property from hidden to block when the radio buttons are selected.

Comment: Thank you both but what I need is to see both the dropdown menu and the text field when the page loads, and the option which is not chosen will be grayed out, and focused when chosen.